# Populating Javascript Table With Parse Database Using Php

Tags: php, database, gridview, parse-platform

Here's an issue I have been battling for a long time.

I found a Javascript gridview table that I installed on my server, it's currently being populated with a JSON file. However, I'm trying to populate it with my parse database, possible with PHP.

Is this even possible with Javascript?

```
<body>
<div style="margin-left:20px;margin-top:100px">
<table width="100%"id="jqGrid"></table>
<div style="margin-left:150px;margin-top:100px;padding-
bottom:110px;"="jqGridPager"></div>
</div>
   <script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#jqGrid").jqGrid({
            url: 
'http://trirand.com/blog/phpjqgrid/examples/jsonp/getjsonp.php?c 
allback=?&qwery=longorders',
            mtype: "GET",
            styleUI : 'Bootstrap',
            datatype: "jsonp",
            colModel: [
                { label: 'OrderID', name: 'OrderID', key: true, width: 75 },
                { label: 'Customer ID', name: 'CustomerID', width: 150 },
                { label: 'Order Date', name: 'OrderDate', width: 150 },
                { label: 'Freight', name: 'Freight', width: 150 },
                { label:'Ship Name', name: 'ShipName', width: 150 }
            ],
            viewrecords: true,
            height: 250,
            rowNum: 20,
            pager: "#jqGridPager"
        });
    });

 </script>
<body>
```

Comment: is the ajax url pointing to your web site or someone elses?

Comment: the url pointing to the demo application, they just use a json file to populate it.

Comment: The url you use is for a demo application for Guriddo jqGrid. My question is: what is returned from your url which uses parse db? - i.e what is the structure and the contend of the returned data. It will help us if you post a example.

Comment: ah yes sorry,
i will be pulling a few types of datasets.
title (string); location (string); submitdate(date);
are a few.i will be pulling it from back4app.

Comment: To avoid having to change your javascript, create a PHP page to query the database and build the JSON file.  Then your javascript will read it to populate the table.